# Discrepancies in OR-tools results between py3.6.4 and py3.6.8

Tags: python, or-tools

I am finding that depending on the exact version of python 3.6 I use when using OR-tools I end up with significantly different results during the solving process.

For my own scheduler I have written if I use 3.6.4 the objective value of the first solution is routinely ~-3600 and the search continues quickly. However, if I use 3.6.8 solution 0's objective value is routinely ~2000 and the search is very slow.

I have tested this on the scheduling example on the github page ( https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py ) and I find a similar thing happens. Strangely, in this example, using 3.6.4 the objective values are returned as a list (ie. [x,y]) whereas using .8 would return a single integer value.

I am unsure what has caused this problem, whether it is on my end or a bug in the solver. Does anyone have any insight into this problem, or is sure if one way is correct or incorrect?

Comment: Are you using the same version of ortools? Can you compare the generated protobufs?

Comment: ah, that may have something to do with it. For 3.6.8 I have ORtools version 7.2.6977, and for .4 I have 7.1.6720. Using 'ipython -m pip show protobuf' I find 3.6.8 is using v3.9.0 and 3.6.4 is using 3.8.0. If you are referring to another protobuf however, I can try find those too.

Comment: I was referring the `model.Proto()` after creating all the variables and contraints but the main reason should be the difference in the ortools version anyway

Comment: ok, I will see if those differ. So I should be able to trust both versions? Is there any reason that they would be finding different objective values or numbers of solutions?